# No module named 'xmlrpclib'

Tags: python, python-3.x, xmlrpclib, yolk

I'm running a python program in Terminal using Python 3.8.2.

After running it on a new device, installing requirements (`pip3 install requirements.txt`), and trying to run (`python3 swift-runner.py`), I got an error saying "No module named yolk"

I hadn't ever gotten that on my original device and was still able to run the program on my original device. So I ran `pip3 install yolk` and then got a new error `No module named 'xmlrpclib'`

I tried recreating the issue on my original device by running `pip3 install yolk` and now I get the same error `No module named 'xmlrpclib'`

Was installing yolk the right approach, where now I just need to install the new module? Or am I going the wrong direction?

Console Messages:

```
Fadis-MacBook-Pro:~ fadisaleh$ python3 /Users/fadisaleh/Downloads/Optimus\ Most\ Updated\ February\ 2020/swift-runner.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/fadisaleh/Downloads/Optimus Most Updated February 2020/swift-runner.py", line 5, in <module>
    from swift.swift import main
  File "/Users/fadisaleh/Downloads/Optimus Most Updated February 2020/swift/swift.py", line 28, in <module>
    from yolk import yolklib, pypi
  File "/Users/fadisaleh/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/yolk/pypi.py", line 20, in <module>
    import xmlrpclib
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xmlrpclib'
```

Comment: It looks like `yolk` is using `xmlrpclib`. You can install it manually with `pip`.

Comment: @nobleknight when I do that I get the following error:

Fadis-MacBook-Pro:~ fadisaleh$ pip3 install xmlrpclib
Collecting xmlrpclib
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement xmlrpclib (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for xmlrpclib